# How to open an URL from command line to Firefox and "switch to tab"?

Tags: command-line, firefox

Firefox 5.0 has the option to "switch to tab" if the requested URL or search terms point to an already open URL (great thing by the way).

Now, to open a URL from command line to Firefox a mere `firefox http://myurl.com` would do, but even if that URL already is open, Firefox will open it once more in another tab.

How can I---from command line---tell Firefox to open the desired URL in an already existing tab if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment.

Comment: its possible  ...

Answer (score 16):

You can do it like:

```
firefox -new-tab "https://www.useotools.com"
```

OR with full path

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-tab "https://www.useotools.com"`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you...

Comment: Not sure why this got so many upvotes, but this command does not switch to an open tab. It just opens the URL in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

Well at least one possible method is to modify your about:config files. See http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/ for details as to how to do this.

Comment: Well that's a cool thing, but it's indiscriminate. What I want is to be able to do that for particular URLs only and at particular times.

Answer (score 0):

`firefox` will work fine; if `DISPLAY` variable has a valid value; if not you need to [set it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095668/5953610)

```
DISPLAY=:0.0; firefox "imgress.com"
```